# receive multiple values from db using ajax

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, database

i know how to validate form using it for 1 field. But i would like enter code and take back multiple values from my db. exmp: price, quantity etc.
It is posible to do using ajac?

php file:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE code='$field_code'";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$query=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);

  if ($row == true) 
  {
      $code = ($row['code']);
      $life = ($row['life']);
      $agree = ($row['agree']);
  }
echo $code;
echo $life;
echo $agree;
?>
```

And script is:

```
$("#field_code").change(function() {
$("#message").html("<img src='pictures/ajax_loader.gif' width='26px' height='26px' /> checking...");


    var data1 = $("#field_code").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'validation.php',

        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function validate(code) {
            if (data == ? ) {

               to do something    
} else {


to do something


            }
```

How to receive all 3 values from php file?
            }
        })

Comment: echo the `$row` using json encode in php then access it as object in js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use json encode for this

```
$values[]= array('code'=>$row['code'], 
                   'life'=>$row['life'],
                   'agree'=>$row['agree']);

echo json_encode($values);
```

and in ajax

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

and access values like `data.life,data.code and data.agree`